# Getting all possible paths in a tree structure

Tags: java, recursion, tree, ontology, wordnet

I need to loop in a tree to get all possible paths, the problem in my code that i get just the first path!

example:
[image]

In the figure, there are 2 paths t handle: 1-2-3-4-5-6 and 1-2-3-7-8 , but i couldn't get both, i have just retrieved 1-2-3-4-5-6 !

**my code:**

In main:

```
for (String key : synset.keySet()) { // looping in a hash of Concept and it's ID
        System.out.println("\nConcept: " + key + " " + synset.get(key));
        List<Concept> ancts = myOntology.getConceptAncestors(myOntology.getConceptFromConceptID(synset.get(key))); // this function retreives the root of any node.

        for (int i = 0; i < ancts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(ancts.get(i).getConceptId() + " # ");
            System.out.print(getChilds(ancts.get(i).getConceptId()) + " -> "); // here, the recursive function is needed to navigate into childs.. 
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Rec. function:

```
public static String getChilds(String conId)
{
    List<Concept> childs = myOntology.getDirectChildren(myOntology.getConceptFromConceptID(conId)); // get all childs of a node
    if(childs.size() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print( childs.size() + " ~ " + childs.get(i).getConceptId() + " -> ");
            return getChilds(childs.get(i).getConceptId());
        }
    }
    else
        return "NULL";
    return "final";
}
```

Comment: The problem ist that you are only providing parts of the info we would need to help you. Without understanding how your tree is really built up (represented internally) we can't say why your algorithm is incorrect. So please step back, turn to the help center and read about http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  besides ... you know that there are many ways to traverse trees? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: I have illustrated the requirement clearly ..

Comment: because of `getChilds` method return `String`. The problem when a node has more than two children

Comment: You have illustrated the **requirement**. You didn't provide the information to help you fix your bug. We are not here to magically figure how the code **you are not showing** is insufficient in regards of your requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't really see enough of your code to use the classes that you have defined. So I went for writing my own working solution.

In the following code, the problem is solved using recursion:

```
public class TreeNode {
    private String id;
    private TreeNode parent;
    private List<TreeNode> children;

    public TreeNode(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.children = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void addChild(TreeNode child) {
        this.children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

    public List<TreeNode> getChildren() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.children);
    }

    private void setParent(TreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

public class TreePaths {
    private static List<List<TreeNode>> getPaths0(TreeNode pos) {
        List<List<TreeNode>> retLists = new ArrayList<>();

        if(pos.getChildren().size() == 0) {
            List<TreeNode> leafList = new LinkedList<>();
            leafList.add(pos);
            retLists.add(leafList);
        } else {
            for (TreeNode node : pos.getChildren()) {
                List<List<TreeNode>> nodeLists = getPaths0(node);
                for (List<TreeNode> nodeList : nodeLists) {
                    nodeList.add(0, pos);
                    retLists.add(nodeList);
                }
            }
        }

        return retLists;
    }

    public static List<List<TreeNode>> getPaths(TreeNode head) {
        if(head == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            return getPaths0(head);
        }
    }
}
```

To use the above code, a tree must be constructed using the `TreeNode` class. Start off by creating a head `TreeNode`, then add child nodes to it as required. The head is then submitted to the `TreePaths getPaths` static function.

After getPaths checks for null, the internal `getPaths0` function will be called. Here we follow a depth first approach by trying to get to all leaf nodes as soon as possible. Once a leaf node is found, a List only containing this leaf node will be created and returned inside the list collection. The parent of this leaf node will then be added to the beginning of the list, which will again be put into a list collection. This will happen for all children of the parent.

In the end, all possible paths will end up in a single structure. This function can be tested as follows:

```
public class TreePathsTest {
    TreeNode[] nodes = new TreeNode[10];

    @Before
    public void init() {
        int count = 0;
        for(TreeNode child : nodes) {
            nodes[count] = new TreeNode(String.valueOf(count));
            count++;
        }
    }

    /*
     * 0 - 1 - 3
     *       - 4
     *   - 2 - 5
     *       - 6
     *       - 7 - 8
     *           - 9
     */
    private void constructBasicTree() {
        nodes[0].addChild(nodes[1]);
        nodes[0].addChild(nodes[2]);
        nodes[1].addChild(nodes[3]);
        nodes[1].addChild(nodes[4]);
        nodes[2].addChild(nodes[5]);
        nodes[2].addChild(nodes[6]);
        nodes[2].addChild(nodes[7]);
        nodes[7].addChild(nodes[8]);
        nodes[7].addChild(nodes[9]);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPaths() {
        constructBasicTree();
        List<List<TreeNode>> lists = TreePaths.getPaths(nodes[0]);
        for(List<TreeNode> list : lists) {
            for(int count = 0; count < list.size(); count++) {
                System.out.print(list.get(count).getId());
                if(count != list.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
0-1-3
0-1-4
0-2-5
0-2-6
0-2-7-8
0-2-7-9
```

Note: The above is enough for manual testing, but the test function should be modified to do proper assertions for proper automated unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this code segment in `getChilds()` exist problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print( childs.size() + " ~ " + childs.get(i).getConceptId()    + " -> ");
        return getChilds(childs.get(i).getConceptId());
}
```

---

the `for loop` cant play a role, it always `return getChilds(childs.get(0).getConceptId());` 
*maybe this is not what you want.*

Comment: yes, that what i thought, but what is the alternative .. ?

Comment: I am afraid that I cant give you advice based on your code for that i dont understand your code for you only present a little your code. **But** about the requirements that **get all possible paths**, there are many solution and **mdewit** has given a feasible solution.

Comment: You're returning in the first pass through the for loop, using index 0 only. Use I instead of 0 and collect all values in a list, then return the list.toString() value - or something similar, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way. 
All you need is a tree traversal and little bit of custom code.

- Have a list called tempPath. you can take it as an argument or a global variable.
- Do a tree traversal(eg. inorder). Whenever you are at a node add this to tempPath list at the end and when you are done with this node remove the node from the end of tempPath.
- whenever you encounter a leaf, you have one full path from root to leaf which is contained in tempPath. you can either print or copy this list value into another data structure.